# ng-model value switching from false to undefined instead of true when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I'm struggling with an input checkbox and the ng-model.
I'm initializing my variable with false, setting it as the ng-model on the input checkbox. When displaying it, the value is false. After clicking on the checkbox the value changes to undefined instead of true.

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
    <input id="check" type="checkbox" ng-model="model.noExpiry" ng-click="model.clickCheck()">Click
    <p>{{model.noExpiry}}</p>
</div>


var module = angular.module("app",[]);

    module.controller("Controller", function ($scope) {
      $scope.model = {};
      $scope.model.noExpiry = false; 

      $scope.model.clickCheck = function(){
        console.log($scope.model.noExpiry);
      }
});
```

If I remove the ng-model and change the model.clickCheck function into the following, it changes correctly the variable from false to true and vice versa:

```
$scope.model.clickCheck = function(){

    if($scope.model.noExpiry) {
        $scope.model.noExpiry = false;
    }
    else {
        $scope.model.noExpiry = true;
    }

    console.log($scope.model.noExpiry);
}
```

When I initialize the model.noExpiry with true, the checkbox turns out to be checked but when unchecking and checking it again, it changes to false and then again to undefined.

Does anybody have an idea why the variable does not change to true but instead to undefined?

AngularJs Version: 1.5.5

Comment: are you initialising your model anywhere? `$scope.model = {};`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey yes, sorry just forgot to write it down

Comment: then you should not be getting an _undefined_, there is a typo or something, but your code is not enough to replicate the issue

Comment: but if this would be the case then why does it always correctly change to false but never to true? and why does it work when using the workaroung with setting the variable through the ng-click function?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `$scope.model` is undefined. So, property `$scope.model.noExpiry` is not valid. Just added `$scope.model = {};` in your controller to make valid object.

> Please check the final updated code:

```js
var module = angular.module("app",[]);
    
    
    module.controller("Controller", function ($scope) {
      $scope.model = {};
      $scope.model.noExpiry = false;

      $scope.model.clickCheck = function(){
        console.log($scope.model.noExpiry);
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
    <input id="check" type="checkbox" ng-model="model.noExpiry" ng-click="model.clickCheck()">Click
    <p>{{model.noExpiry}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: am I seeing it right that you just added the "$scope.model = {};"? i just forgot to write it down...it does not work for me

Comment: Already working code snippet added, and its working in snippet. have you checked the snippet

Comment: Do you use the code: if($scope.model.noExpiry) {
        $scope.model.noExpiry = false;
    }
    else {
        $scope.model.noExpiry = true;
    }

Comment: Because your ng-model for checkbox will do that for you. Your above condition may create problem.

Comment: i use it as a workaround. if i only use the ng-model with initializing the model and model.noExpiry=false it dows not work

Comment: @Lea do you mean angularjs 1.4? or angular 2.4? they are completely different

Comment: @AlekseySolovey need to correct myself...version is 1.5.5